# "restricting" an algebra to a subspace while keeping it associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an associative and commutative algebra $A$ and a linear subspace $B$ of $A$. I want to equip $B$ with a multiplication $\odot$ so that

- $\odot$ is associative and commutative,
- $\odot$ is compatible with multiplication in $A$, in the sense that $x\odot y = x\cdot y$ whenever $x,y$ and $x\cdot y$ are all in $B$.

Is there a standard construction for doing this? For instance if I find a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $B$, extend it to a basis $\mathcal{A}$ of $A$, write down structure coefficients in terms of $\mathcal{A}$, and set to zero all coefficients involving basis elements in $\mathcal{A}\setminus \mathcal{B}$, I will get a multiplication $\odot$ on $B$ satisfying the second property, but which is not generally associative.

---

Here's a simple example I was playing around with. Consider the cosine basis $$b_i = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}, & i=0\\ \frac{\cos(ix/2)}{2\sqrt{\pi}}, & i > 0\end{cases}$$
for real-valued functions on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f'(0)=f'(2\pi) = 0$, and take
$$\mathcal{A} = \{b_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}, \quad \mathcal{B} = \{b_i\}_{i=0}^N$$
for some finite $N$. Because of the cosine product law
$$\cos(ax)\cos(bx) = \frac{\cos([a+b]x) + \cos([a-b]x)}{2},$$
the structure coefficients of $\mathcal{A}$ are fairly straightfoward to compute. Writing $C^k$ for the $N\times N$ matrix containing the coefficients $c_{ij}^k$ for $1\leq i,j\leq N$, we have for example for $N=10$

$$C^1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$C^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
etc. Imposing these matrices as the structure coefficients of $B$ does not yield an associative $\odot$; a necessary condition is that the matrices $C^k$ commute, but for instance 
$$[C^1,C^2] = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4 \pi } \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{4 \pi } & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

I this case, by inspecting the symmetry of $C^k$ one can infer how to "fix" $\odot$; imposing on $\mathcal{B}$ the structure coefficients
$$\bar{C}^3 = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
etc, yields an $\odot$ with both above properties.

But I'm hoping for a systematic construction, as I'm particularly interested in the case where $A=L^2(S^2)$ and $B$ is the span of the first $N$ spherical harmonics, and the structure coefficients are far less pleasant.

Comment: Can we assume these to be finite dimensional?

Comment: @Berci I eventually want to apply this technique to the case where $A$ is infinite-dimensional and $B$ is finite; but an answer assuming both are finite would already be useful to me.

Comment: Do you have a specific example when your construction is not associative?

Comment: @Berci The case I am particularly interested in is $A=L^2(S^2)$ and $B$ the span of the first $N$ spherical harmonics.